# Register Device with Splinter and Save Session

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver, splinter

I'm using Splinter to scrub my bank accounts and run some automated financial calcs for me. I recently switched banks (Now at Huntington) and my new bank requires you to register a known device unless you want to get a text code every-time you login. I know cookies are loading correctly because if I load them right after saving them I don't need to login as my session has not timed out. I have gone through the process of saving and reloading the cookies every time I use login but for some reason the website flags me as an unknown device...

What is changing that they can see on there end and how I do I carry it over between program launches???

```
def huntington_login(cok='cookies.cok'):
    # OPEN BROWSER AND LOAD COOKIES
    login_url = 'https://www.huntington.com/'
    browser = Browser(cfg.browser,headless=cfg.browser_headless)
    browser.visit(login_url)
    f = open(cok,'rb')
    cookies = pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    browser.cookies.add(cookies)
    browser.visit(login_url)

    # DO SECRET STUFF HERE TO LOGIN

    # DO SECRET STUFF HERE TO SCRUB BANK

    # SAVE COOKIES
    cookies = browser_get_cookies(browser)
    f = open(cok,'wb')
    pickle.dump(cookies,f)
    f.close()

    browser.quit()
```